# Log into Chrome Extension without OAuth2

Tags: django, authentication, post, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0

I'm wondering if it's possible to set up secure login authentication in a Chrome extension **without OAuth2**. I'm considering setting it up as follows:

1. On opening the extension, send a POST to server which returns the CSRF token
2. JavaScript inserts the token into the usual login form (as in Django template)

[steps 1 and 2 replace the usual Django template rendering]

3. User provides username and password and submits the form
4. Success/Fail JSON response is returned and handled appropriately
5. CSRF token is stored as a cookie (or in browser storage that Chrome extensions use) to enable automated login until it expires

Would be great to hear possible problems/corrections to this approach as well as pointers to relevant resources!

== UPDATE ==

It seems like `chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow` is the way to go. I found resources that explain how to implement it client-side but they all say nothing about how to authenticate server-side for non-Google accounts:

- [*"The provider will perform authentication*" - how?](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity#non)
- [*"Validation of the returned access token isn't shown here"*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/identity/launchWebAuthFlow)

It seems that the last missing ingredient is to write code that validates a URL such as:

```
https://www.my-app.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=123456789012345&
redirect_uri=https://abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdef.chromiumapp.org/provider_cb&response_type=token&scope=user_photos
```

That will surely be done by another Chrome Identity API call from my application's server. I looked through [a](https://smus.com/oauth2-chrome-extensions/) [large](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_oauth) [number](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) [of](https://medium.com/google-cloud/understanding-oauth2-and-building-a-basic-authorization-server-of-your-own-a-beginners-guide-cf7451a16f66) [resources](https://medium.com/@ratrosy/building-a-basic-authorization-server-using-authorization-code-flow-c06866859fb1) (and [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093624/google-chrome-extension-login-functionality) [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287061/log-in-to-my-web-from-a-chrome-extension) [overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37748463/login-authentication-in-chrome-extension-practice) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23139224/log-in-to-a-chrome-app-or-extension)) and they provide no clear answer. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you're avoiding OAuth2?

Comment: I don't want people to have to 'log in with Google'. Maybe this is something I'm misunderstanding and I can use OAuth2 and still have people log in with credentials they'd set up on my site?