# Authenticate non-Google account in Chrome extension using OAuth2

Tags: google-chrome, authentication, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-api

It seems like [`chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity#method-launchWebAuthFlow) is the way to go. I found resources that explain how to implement it client-side but they all say nothing about how to authenticate server-side for non-Google accounts:

- [*"The provider will perform authentication*" - how?](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity#non)
- [*"Validation of the returned access token isn't shown here"*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/identity/launchWebAuthFlow)

It seems that the last missing ingredient is to write **server-side** (ideally Python) code that listens on my app's server and validates URLs such as:

```
https://www.my-app.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=123456789012345&redirect_uri=https://abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdef.chromiumapp.org/provider_cb&response_type=token&scope=user_photos
```

I'm guessing that would be done by another Chrome Identity API call from my application's server. I looked through [a](https://smus.com/oauth2-chrome-extensions/) [large](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_oauth) [number](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) [of](https://medium.com/google-cloud/understanding-oauth2-and-building-a-basic-authorization-server-of-your-own-a-beginners-guide-cf7451a16f66) [resources](https://medium.com/@ratrosy/building-a-basic-authorization-server-using-authorization-code-flow-c06866859fb1) (and [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093624/google-chrome-extension-login-functionality) [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287061/log-in-to-my-web-from-a-chrome-extension) [overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37748463/login-authentication-in-chrome-extension-practice) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23139224/log-in-to-a-chrome-app-or-extension)) and they provide no clear answer. Thanks!

[migrated discussion here from [this question]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59045885/log-into-chrome-extension-without-oauth2)